gateway in network with one address
I have got a (virtual) machine with an IP Address 10.X.Y.27/32.
I want to

reach this machine via network
reach another machine from this machine via an existing IP set tunnel (from 10.A.B.0/25 to 10.X.Y.27/32).

I see the problem that the gateway can only be the same address than the address of the machine itself.
I did:
ip route add default via 10.X.Y.27
ip route
default via 10.X.Y.27 dev eth0
ping 10.A.B.40
From 10.X.Y.27 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

When trying to access that machine from local network (which is opened to that network) I am redirected to my firewall.
The machine am using runs Debian 12.
From my firewall (pfsense) I can ping that machine in the ipsec tunnel  when using the virtual network of the machine as source address.

What is the address of the actual gateway for this network? How did you conclude that "the gateway can only be the same address than the address of the machine itself"? (Does using the machine's own address as 'gateway' make any logical sense?)

You can't have a network with a /32 subnet; a /32 address can only be used for a loopback interface (because it routes to itself). The smallest "real" network is /30, although there are use cases for /31 networks.
